# What's the usage of the code signing identity of Release in the project of Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

As far as I know that the code signing identity is used to sign the app. And the code signing identity is useful for Debug (with Developer certificate in Build Setting->Code Signing Identity) because the app will be run directly on the provisioned device

But why there is an option below the Debug called Release?

If we want to distribute our app, we need to archive it first. And then export it to ipa. In the process of export, the Xcode will pop-up a window to let you choose the Distribution Certificate again.

So if we can choose the distribute certificate here, why we need to specify the certificate in the project setting? (in Build Setting->Code Signing Identity, Release)?

What confuses me further is that even if I specify the Developer certificate in the Release (just the same certificate as I specify in the Debug), I can archive the app successfully. It looks like that the Release section is useless.

I also checked the archive and found that the app is signed. So another question is the export from archive to ipa is a process of re-signing?

P.S I used the XCode 5 and 6.

Comment: You are expected to test the app built with Release (or whatever configuration you use for the final builds) configuration and although it leaves a place for errors if you run it via Xcode, it saves a significant amount of time to do so when you are testing the app yourself.

Comment: @A-Live, If we launch the app on device directly from the Xcode, we use the Debug configuration. If we create the ad-hoc app for testing, as I said, the export from archive to ad-hoc will pop-up a window to let me choose the certificate again, not automatically use the certificate I specify in the Release configuration. So I don't quite understand why Xcode provides the Release configuration for distribution certificate and don't use it (pop-up again when exporting)

Answer (score 3):

Debug and Release are simply the default "build configurations" Xcode generates for you, when you create a new project.

On one hand, you can modify stuff like the compiler optimizations and linking or stripping behavior used between Debug and Release build configurations -- e.g. stripping debug symbols or not.

On the other hand, you can use these build configurations to define compile-time defines, possibly changing some default setting you have, that are only germane at compile-time. For e.g., `#if DEBUG` or `#if RELEASE` maybe could wrap an NSString or NSURL that defines your default web server -- one for localhost, or your live-production server (as a simple example).

Now, you can also change code signing and provisioning settings between build configurations. For a simple app, you may not care about this much at all. In other cases however, maybe the provisioning you setup for "Release" enables different in-app features (e.g. push notifications maybe?) where Debug does not. The different provisioning may also point to Apple's sandbox servers v. live, for Debug or Release. (I think this address the core question you have of why you'd ever want to do this.)

These (quite sensibly named defaults) are really just there for you to fit to you and your team's use cases. For e.g., my team has a project that has Debug, Staging, and Release build configurations. There are compiler optimizations that differ between all of them, and we use the different configurations to compile-in/out and link-in (or not) certain sections of code that only make sense in Staging, where they may not make sense in Release. We /also/ have different teams that share the code base. In our case when we "ship" source code to the client, and as a final step before doing so, we make sure it builds and runs with their code-signing and provisioning setup.

As another example, I often change the build configuration Archive uses depending on to-whom or where I am delivering the build product. This isn't a setting I consider static.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks greymouser. This helps me a lot on understanding the configuration. But the point of this question is that in the Building Setting->Code Signing Identiy, we shall choose the certificate for each configuration (Debug or Release). I don't know what the certificate of Release configuration is used for. If it's used for distribution, then after the app is archived and ready to export to iPA (ad hoc or submit to app store), Xcode will ask me again to choose the distribution certificate. It doesn't automatically use the certificate in the configuration.

Comment: @RoyMa If you log into Apple Dev Center, and head to the provisioning portal, and look at Certificates->All, you'll see that you and your devs have "personal" certificates labeled as "iOS Development", and there will be others for "production". When you originally made the certificates (and if you click the "+" there you can see the interface again), it asked you what sort of certificate you were making: development, or one of the various production related certificates (of which the "main" one is "App Store and Ad Hoc", but there are plenty of others). 1/2

Comment: @RoyMa The Code Signing Identity informs Xcode which cert to attempt to use when signing, and also relates to the provisioning profile selected; the identity chosen needs to be able to actually use the provisioning profile. For development, this is often completely transparent, since you are likely automatically using the default iOS Team Provisioning that Apple creates for the account. If you have a team of developers, for e.g., you'd like want the code signing identity to be set to the magic string "iPhone Developer", which will attempt to discover the appropriate identity on the team. 2/2